# how to check if an Emacs frame is maximized on MS Windows?

Tags: windows, emacs

The expression

```
(frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen)
```

returns `nil` even when the frame is maximized.

Answer (score 1):

```
(cdr (assoc 'fullscreen (frame-parameters)))
```

should retur 'fullboth when maximized in both sides.

Answer (score 0):

I thnk it depends on how you maximized it: if you just told your window-manager to maximize, Emacs won't know about it.  Whereas if you told Emacs to maximize the frame the `fullscreen` frame-parameter should be non-nil (IOW if it's nil, you should report it to `M-x report-emacs-bug`).